# Specific dates in one event joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I want to add an event with specific dates that kind of functionality i tried lots of components but no success.

Is there any component availble in Joomla that does this functionality ?

If not then can you please advise on this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried an events component such as JEvents?

Comment: yes I tried that component. But I want functionality like if i add event name,description then there should be different dates to that same event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repeating events?!?

I could find only commercial extensions:

1. [Event Registration Pro](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/calendars-a-events/events/events-registration/3458)
2. [Zap Calendar](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/calendars-a-events/events/events-calendars/8587)
3. [Jtag Calendar](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/calendars-a-events/events/events-calendars/17043)
4. [Spider Calendar](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/calendars-a-events/events/events-calendars/22329)
5. [JE Ajax event calendar](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/calendars-a-events/events/events-calendars/12110)

Non-Commercial:

1. [JEvent](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/calendars-a-events/events/events-calendars/95)

If there is something else you are looking for please explain further.

Comment: Hi it is not exactly like repeating events its like it should able to save event name with different specific start dates and end dates

Comment: In that case try iCagenda - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/calendars-a-events/events/events-management/22013  

It is Non-Commercial and very popular!

Comment: Do you want to have it like, for example, how it would be for an online course where the same course can have multiple dates and the user can choose which one to take up? basically giving an option to the user to select one of the multiple dates for the same event. is that it?

Comment: yes vishal you are right! but in mine one it is event name,description and you can select multiple dates for that event.

Comment: Thanks vishal this icagenda does exact functionality I want. Thanks again!